# Passing State to another Component in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-component

React Native **Newbie** here.

I have an (in my opinion) common use case here. I work with React Navigation and have 4 different Tabs. In the first Tab I have a FlatList from which I want to choose Favourites. These Favourites should be then listed in the other Tab. Nothing more so far.

The Problem I encounter is that I'm not figuring out how I can transmit the favourites variable declared in my state of the first tab, to the other Tab. Maybe the approach is completely wrong too..

**First Tab/Screen**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View, ScrollView, Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [],
    favourites: []
  };

  //Function called on the click of the Heart Button, adding the List Element to the State
  addFav = item => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({'favourites': prevState.favourites+item.title+' '}))
    alert(item.title)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  //Fetching the data from the API
  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.19:8080/v1/api/event");
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json});
  };

  render() {
    return <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() =>
            <View
              style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}
            />
          }
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(item => item.title)}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <ScrollView>
              <Image style={{alignSelf:'stretch', width:undefined, height:undefined, flex : 1, borderRadius:10}} source = {require('../img/landscape.jpeg')}/>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.openEvent(item)}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'row', padding: 5}}>
                  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:15, textAlign:'center', padding: 2}}>{this.timeConverterMonth(item.time)}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:15, textAlign:'center', padding: 2}}>{this.timeConverterDay(item.time)}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{flex: 4}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:15, padding: 2}}>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:10, padding: 2}}>{item.locShort}</Text>
                  </View>
//That's where the function is called
                  <TouchableHighlight 
                    style={{flex: 2}} 
                    onPress={() => this.addFav(item)}
                  >
                    <Icon name="ios-heart-empty" size={24} style={{alignSelf: 'center', padding: 10}}/>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
//just checking the state
              <Text>{this.state.favourites}</Text>
            </ScrollView>}
        />;
  }
}
```

**Second Tab/Screen**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default class FavouritesScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
//Here I want to display my favourites Array from the HomeScreen State
    return <Text>{this.props.favourites}</Text>;
  }
}
```

I am actually not wondering why it's not functioning, I just tried the props method by reading all the other articles but the Screens are not in Parent/Child relation.

So what I want to do would be in the Second Tab something like

```
HomeScreen.state.favourites
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your case is a very common one. One I faced was passing a 'shared state' between the application.

The components have a local state, which you can pass to child components via props (which you have mentioned).

The problem arises when you want to access that state in another component. The solution here is having a global state.

You may want to consider Redux for your application.

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

From the redux website:

> Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.
>
> It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in
>   different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to
>   test. On top of that, it provides a great developer experience, such
>   as live code editing combined with a time traveling debugger.

Essentially, you'll be getting a global state which can be accessed by all your application's components. This allows you to update states within one component and access them in another.

I will warn you, it's not the easiest thing to learn. When you first look at it - it's a bit daunting. But, as your application grows in complexity and you add more state - you'll be glad you used it.

The good news is, Redux is very well documented with React and React Native - so you should find lots of tutorials on how to integrate it into your current application.

Answer (score 1):

Your usecase of having "globally" accessed state is where state management libraries come in. One good example is the libary Redux - in this case you could store the favourites under a piece of state called "HomeScreen" and map it and use it in any screen in the rest of the app.

Here is a good article about getting started with redux: https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29